# Error in if (min(gf) >= 0) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed in maximum likelihood estimation of haplotype frequency function code

Tags: r, genetics

In 64th line of the code an error is throwing in and I have no idea how to get rid of this (and make further code executable) :

> Error in if (min(gf) >= 0) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The code estimates maximum likelihood estimation of haplotype frequency. It works right until it hits problematic loop, then the execution of the code abruptly stops. In general I have to calculate the log likelihood.

The problematic code:

```r
PA <- 0.7
PB <- 0.6
d<- 0.1
r <- d /sqrt(PA*Pa*PB*Pb)
make.hap.freq<-function(PA,PB,r){
    Pa <- 1-PA
    Pb <- 1-PB
    ret <- c(PA*PB,PA*Pb,Pa*PB,Pa*Pb)
    ret <- ret + c(d,-d,-d,d)
    ret
}

make.gen.freq <- function(PA,PB,r){
    h <- make.hap.freq(PA,PB,r)
    g <- matrix(0,3,3)
    g[1,1] <- h[1]^2
    g[1,3] <- h[2]^2
    g[3,1] <- h[3]^2
    g[3,3] <- h[4]^2
    g[1,2] <- 2*h[1] * h[2]
    g[2,1] <- 2*h[1] * h[3]
    g[2,3] <- 2*h[2] * h[4]
    g[3,2] <- 2*h[3] * h[4]
    g[2,2] <- 2*(h[1] * h[4] + h[2] * h[3])
    g
}


make.hap.freq(PA,PB,r)

make.gen.freq(PA,PB,r)


#########
## 7 Diplotype data simulation for 2 SNVs
#########

gf <- make.gen.freq(PA,PB,r)
N <- 1000
G <- sample(1:9, N, replace=TRUE,prob =gf)
tabulate(G)
matrix(tabulate(G), 3,3)

#########
## 8 Maximum likelihood estimation of haplotype frequency
#########
# Assume you have 3x3 diplotype counts data only.
# Based on the table, you can estimate haplotype frequency.


Gmat= matrix(c(20,24,5,14,22,6,2,2,5))
Gmat.rsum <- apply(Gmat,1,sum)
Gmat.csum <- apply(Gmat,2,sum)

PA <- (2*Gmat.rsum[1]+Gmat.rsum[2])/(2*sum(Gmat.rsum))
PB <- (2*Gmat.csum[1]+Gmat.csum[2])/(2*sum(Gmat.csum))


rs <- seq(from=-1,to=1,length=100)
logLike <- rep(NA,length(rs))
for(i in 1:length(rs)){
    tmp.r <- rs[i]
    gf <- make.gen.freq(PA,PB,tmp.r)


############
######This is the problematic loop:


    if(min(gf)>=0){
        logLike[i] <- dmultinom(c(Gmat),prob=c(gf),log=TRUE)
    }
}
plot(rs,logLike)

ml.r <- rs[which(logLike==max(logLike,na.rm=TRUE))]

abline(v=ml.r)
abline(h=max(logLike,na.rm=TRUE))

ml.hf <- make.hap.freq(PA,PB,ml.r)
```

I've corrrected the code. However, I've still haven't arrived at the correct answer.

> Using the command 'dmultinom(c(Gmat),prob=c(gf),log=TRUE)', calculate the log likelihood. There is a way to find the value of d, or the value set of haplotype frequency, that maximizes this likelihood and its result is called the maximum likelihood estimate of haplotype frequency for 2 SNVs.

```r
PA=0.7
PB=0.6
Pa=0.3
Pb=0.4
d=0.1
r <- d /sqrt(PA*Pa*PB*Pb)
make.hap.freq<-function(PA,PB,r){
    ret1 = c(PA*PB,PA*Pb,Pa*PB,Pa*Pb)
    ret = ret1 + c(d,-d,-d,d)
    ret
}

make.gen.freq <- function(PA,PB,r){
    h <- make.hap.freq(PA,PB,r)
    g <- matrix(0,3,3)
    g[1,1] <- h[1]^2
    g[1,3] <- h[2]^2
    g[3,1] <- h[3]^2
    g[3,3] <- h[4]^2
    g[1,2] <- 2*h[1] * h[2]
    g[2,1] <- 2*h[1] * h[3]
    g[2,3] <- 2*h[2] * h[4]
    g[3,2] <- 2*h[3] * h[4]
    g[2,2] <- 2*(h[1] * h[4] + h[2] * h[3])
    g
}


make.hap.freq(PA,PB,r)

make.gen.freq(PA,PB,r)


#########
## 7 Diplotype data simulation for 2 SNVs
#########

gf <- make.gen.freq(PA,PB,r)

#########
## 8 Maximum likelihood estimation of haplotype frequency
#########
# Assume you have 3x3 diplotype counts data only.
# Based on the table, you can estimate haplotype frequency.

N <- 1000
G <- sample(1:9, N, replace=TRUE,prob =gf)
tabulate(G)
matrix(tabulate(G), 3,3)

tabulate(G)
Gmat <- matrix(tabulate(G), 3,3)
Gmat.rsum <- apply(Gmat,1,sum)
Gmat.csum <- apply(Gmat,2,sum)

PA <- (2*Gmat.rsum[1]+Gmat.rsum[2])/(2*sum(Gmat.rsum))
PB <- (2*Gmat.csum[1]+Gmat.csum[2])/(2*sum(Gmat.csum))


rs <- seq(from=-1,to=1,length=100)
logLike <- rep(NA,length(rs))
for(i in 1:length(rs)){
    tmp.r <- rs[i]
    gf <- make.gen.freq(PA,PB,tmp.r)


############
######This is the problematic loop:


    if(min(gf)>=0){
        logLike[i] <- dmultinom(c(Gmat),prob=c(gf),log=TRUE)
    }
}
plot(rs,logLike)

ml.r <- rs[which(logLike==max(logLike,na.rm=TRUE))]

abline(v=ml.r)
abline(h=max(logLike,na.rm=TRUE))

ml.hf <- make.hap.freq(PA,PB,ml.r)
```

Comment: you may have some `NA` values in `gf`. What is output of `sum(is.na(gf))`?

Comment: Actually, running your code produces matrix for `gf` that contains only `NA` values, hence the error as the `>=` operator needs a numeric value on the left side. *Tip*: Always inspect the object that leads to the error, in this case `gf`.

Comment: I've corrected the code, as it can be seen in my edited post @Vince

Comment: hey, there's something weird about your first part, make.hap.freq<-function(PA,PB,r); r is not used in the function, instead d is used, and d is defined as 0.1 . is it r or d in make.hap.freq?

Comment: The part to calculate r was previously in the loop - and it was at the begining to calculate d, as the r was known. Now the conditions have changed - I know d, so I've changed the code, but then I moved back from d to r.

Comment: Let me be a bit more specific, this line, ret = ret1 + c(d,-d,-d,d) ; if you don't call d in your function, make.hap.freq<-function(PA,PB,r) , then you are always returning ret1 + c(d,-d,-d,d) where d=-1 . Can you update your function and remove the r if it is not needed?

Comment: I asked about this because in your later part, gf <- make.gen.freq(PA,PB,tmp.r), the tmp.r is basically a useless variable